# Differences between "por fim" and "enfim"

Tags: português-europeu

Are there any differences in usage between "por fim" and "enfim"? I've been told that the latter is seldom used in European Portuguese, and its use is restricted to only a few cases. Is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, In Brazilian Portuguese there are a few differences in meaning and the two phrases are not always interchangeable. The Priberam defines [**"enfim"**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/enfim) as...

> en·fim (em + fim) advérbio
>
> 1. Por último; em último lugar.
> 2. Depois de ser muito esperado (ex.: enfim, chegaram!).
> 3. Expressão usada para acrescentar algo ao que já foi dito.
> 4. Em suma; em conclusão.

Definitions 2 e 4 are current usage pt-BR.
examples:

- "Enfim encontro alguém que me entende" (finalmente)
- "Enfim, nada do que tu possas dizer ou fazer vai mudar alguma coisa." (em suma, concluindo - note the brief pause after "enfim", in this case.)

"por fim" may have the same meaning 1 as "enfim" (finalmente, por último) e.g. "Por fim (depois de pensar a respeito) eles decidiram que a melhor coisa a fazer era vender a casa" ou "Por fim, eu gostaria de agradecer a todos aqueles que..."

When we want to express impatience about somelhting that has long been awaited, "enfim" and "por fim" are not interchangeable. In such cases we use "enfim" only and there is no pause after it.

- "enfim publicaram os resultados"
- "enfim já posso ir embora."

Comment: @ANeves  O Priberam é um dicionário português e, para a definição nº 2 de "enfim", não há nenhuma indicação de que seja um brasileirismo.

Comment: @Centaurus o OP faz duas perguntas, você "só" responde à primeira parte...

Comment: (A resposta ficou mais clara com a edição, obrigado.)

Comment: Centaurus, I think we don't use "enfim" *without* the pause, in Portugal. (The example for 2 has the pause.) Enfim, uma resposta sobre o uso brasileiro é melhor do que nada. :)

Comment: @ANeves   Agradeço você achar que a minha resposta é melhor do que nada. Muito obrigado.

Comment: "até que enfim publicaram os resultados"

Comment: Francamente, eu acho que enfim é usado da mesma maneira dos dois lados do atlántico e as duas expressões também são diferentes da mesma maneira nos dois lados do atlántico. Quando não há diferencia, é bom dizê-lo. Senão a confusão aumenta.